# Apk download with php gives undefined but download works after browser refresh

Tags: php, apk

```
<a href="download.php"><img src="images/android/android01.jpg"/>Android</a>
```

links to:

php code:

```
$file = 'myfile.apk';
$filename ="MYAPP";
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

I get an undefined output on Firefox desktop browser and phone. When I do a browser refresh, the download dialog starts and downloads the apk file.
Any ideas on how I can get around the undefined output in a blank page and go to download dialog immediatly?

Comment: what do you mean by undefined output?

Comment: a blank webpage returns with thw word undefined on the first line..

Comment: huh? that's strange... only 'undefined' nothing else?

Comment: when doing a browser refresh only the the download dialog starts

Comment: sounds like an error somewhere else but not in this part of the script. btw I suggest appending .apk to the filename...

Comment: put this code in a single file which is independant from the rest of your code then test again. if the error is gone it is somewhere else...

Comment: works when I call the php code directly: localhost/download.php

Comment: from browser url bar but fails from another page in href tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.location='download.php'">
  <img src="images/android/android01.jpg"/>Android
</a>
```